# Функция file_get_contents возвращает пустую строку

Tags: php

Доброе время суток!

Есть вот такой код:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
ini_set("user_agent" , "Mozilla/3.0\r\nAccept: */*\r\nX-Padding: Foo");

if(isset($_GET["refid"])) {
    $stats = file_get_contents("http://tankionline.com/referer/$refid.xml");
    if($stats != "") {
        preg_match_all('#<scores>(.+?)</scores>#is', $str, $arr);
        die($arr[1]);
    } else {
        echo 'err_incorrect_refid<br>Var dump: ';
        var_dump($stats);
    }   
} else {
    die("err_no_refid_found");
}
```

Существующий refid = d574a4552.
Собственно он и передается скрипту. Скрипт возвращает:

```
err_incorrect_refid
Var dump: bool(false)
```

В браузере ссылку открывает.

php.ini настроен правильно... вроде бы.

Заранее благодарен.

P.S. Загрузка этого же файла с той же машины, только через консоль.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: только не говорите, что у вас включена директива register_globals =))))), а то судя по этому 

>>$_GET["refid"] и $refid 

оно так и есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"http://tankionline.com/referer/$refid.xml"
```

Возможно, интерпретатор решил, что Вы хотите обратиться к свойству экземпляра класса `$refid.xml`. Чтобы такого не было, можно, как вариант, заключить `$refid` в фигурные скобки.

```
"http://tankionline.com/referer/{$refid}.xml"
```

Comment: А, нет, ошибся. Похоже, помогло.
Вырубил `register_globals` и добавил `{$refid}`.

Спасибо всем!